# Translate FriendlyID slugs to a corresponding ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, slug, friendly-id

I have a comments scaffold and a movies scaffold.

Users can comment on movie in this path /movies/the-social-network/comments/new

My issue is that the comments use movie_id to work and to link with the movies.

So what I'm asking is how to pass the-social-network as the movie_id?

PS: Im using Friendly Id 4

Answer (score 1):

First, since you want to look up `Movie` by "slug" like `the-social-network`, you need to extend `FriendlyId` and tell it to parameterize the `id` into an attribute called `slug`. Do this by passing `:slugged` as follows:

```
# app/models/movie.rb
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

Then, create a migration to store `slug` for `Movie` objects:

```
# in console
rails g migration add_slug_to_movies slug:string
```

Modify the migration file to add `slug` as an index:

```
# change migration file
class AddSlugToMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :movies, :slug, :string
        add_index :movies, :slug
    end
end
```

Finally, you need to create a slug for all the existing movies in your database. You can do this by saving each movie one-by-one:

```
# in Rails console 
Movie.find_each(&:save)
```

After you'd done this, you should be able to make lookups on `Movie` akin to `/movies/the-social-network/comments/new`.

Check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) for additional details and examples, including ensuring that an object's slug is correctly update when the title is changed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). For example, if `movie_name` is 'the-social-network', this will work:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    movie_name
  end
end
```